# App name is not translated

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli, django-i18n

Can't figure out why my app is not translated.
Here is the what I have in `django.po` file:

```
#: products/__init__.py:4
msgid "Products"
msgstr "Продукты"
```

And I've put this into app's `__init__` file:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
_('Products')
```

And here's what I have in template:

```
<h2>{% trans app.name %}</h2>
```

I've compiled `.po` file, i18n and l10n in settings are turned on. App's name translation doesn't work though.

UPDATE:
now I can see app name translated in breadcrumbs on app's models objects lists pages, but not on index and app's models list pages.

Comment: ehh how are you passing the `app` to the template context, what is a `app`?

Comment: is `{% load i18n %}` in your template? [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code)

Comment: @lalo, it's admin`s `index.html` template. There's loop which outputs all apps names.

Comment: You said you have a `.po` file, did you also compile it to an `.mo` file?

Comment: @HermanSchaaf, yes I did.

Comment: did you restart the server?

Comment: and your app name is `Products`, with a capital `P`? ;)

Comment: @HermanSchaaf, I've tried `products` too, didn't work.

Comment: did you set the `LANGUAGES` in settings file?

Comment: @lalo, I don't know what this LANGUAGES setting is actually for, but I've added it like in docs and it didn't work.